# What is inner voltage

Tags: voltage, power, generator, synchronous

I'm currently studying Power Systems, and I stumbled upon "Inner voltage" I tried to search about it. However, very little is written about it. Could someone explain what it is?

**Edit: Someone people wanted to know in what context this term is used. It's used in regards to synchronous machines and generators.**

Comment: Perhaps some context about where you found this term?  Can you provide a reference?

Comment: You need to give some context. Quote the article and give a reference to the document.

Comment: @jwh20 and Transistor I edited my post :)

Comment: Again, please be more specific.  Where do you see this term?  I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: This may be an auto translation problem? Again, link to the source...

Comment: I'm wondering if the term "inner voltage" might be synonymous with "back EMF" but there is a language barrier.

Comment: When I google "synchronous generator inner voltage" I find quite a few university slides labeling the open circuit voltage of the generator as "inner / internal voltage"

Comment: @jwh20 it's just mentioned in a list, "Explain what inner voltage is". I contacted a friend of mine, he said "it's the EMF that is induced inside the stator winding".

Comment: I think it could be the 'virtual' voltage sythesized by the control scheme as an observer for the real one, something like simulated ramp correction in switchers. But I'm not really expert on the field.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the EMF on the stator.  The rotating magnetic field in the machine induces an EMF on the stator windings which is more or less distributed along the length of the wiring.  Since the windings have a finite resistance, the stator windings can be modeled as an ideal voltage source (representing the induced EMF) in series with a resistor (representing the winding resistance).  The "internal voltage" is the magnitude of the ideal voltage source, which can be closely approximated by the open circuit voltage.

Comment: I concur.........